# Gradle throwing exception in a Hello World project

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I am trying to add Firebase and google services to my flutter app however Gradle is throwing an exception without any real explanation.

I tried reinstalling both android studio and flutter however the error still happens. I also downloaded the google-services.json file and placed it within the app folder.

My project level gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }

   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
   project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
   project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app level gradle looks like this

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.facial_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error message produced is:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\facial_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\facial_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\facial_app\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to AndroidX compatibility,
Create a new project and follow the steps below:

1. In order for your project to be AndroidX compatible, you need to add the following two lines to your *gradle.properties* file:

   ```
   android.useAndroidX = true
   android.enableJetifier = true
   ```
2. Make sure in your *app build.gradle file* that the *compileSdkVersion* and *targetSdkVersion* are both set to ***28***
3. Remove all the lines with the comment "*Remove*" from your main *app build.gradle file*:

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 28

   lintOptions {
       disable 'InvalidPackage'
   }

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 28
       versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
       versionName flutterVersionName
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" //Remove
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
      }
    }


   dependencies {
       testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' // Remove
       androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' // Remove
   }
   ```
4. If you try to build the project you will get an error that has something to do with the core library for AndroidX, To fix it, add the code in the ***subprojects*** category in your *project level build.gradle* file:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
       }

   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
   }

   subprojects {
       project.configurations.all {
           resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
               if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                       && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                   details.useVersion "1.0.1"
               }
           }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

NOTE 1: In the 4th step rememeber that the subprojects category should be bellow the dependecies category, if not present then copy and paste the code given.

I would prefer to try the above steps in Android Studio, Save all the files and restart the project, Add the Firebase dependencies and whatever the changes are told to do in the documentation: [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup). It would work.

BEST OF LUCK!!

Comment: Your welcome,  i am happy that i helped you. Actually I had the exact problem a couple of days ago